# How to Remove any consecutive sequence in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to solve this.
Nominal Case:

For the array[1,2,3,5,2,4,7,54], and the number 6. The sequences[1,2,3] and [4,2] will be removed because the add up to 6. function will return [5,7,54]. If two sequences overlap, remove the first sequence.

Overlapping Case:

For the array [1,2,3,9,4,1,4,6,7] and the number 5, the sequence [2,3,] and [4,1] are removed because they add up to 5. For the [4,1] case. you see that [4,1,4] represents two overlapping sequences. because [4,1] adds up to 5 first is removed and the 4 is not removed even  through  [1,4] adds up to 5. We say that [4,1] and [1,4] overlap to give [4,1,4] and in those cases the first of the overlapping sequences is removed . functin will return [1,9,4,6,7]

```js
function consecutive(arr, len, num) {
  var newarr = [];
  for (let i = 1; i < len; i++) {
    var sum = arr[i] + arr[i + 1];
    if (sum == num) {
      newarr.push(arr[i]);
      newarr.push(arr[i + 1]);
    }
  }
  return newarr;
}

let arr = [1, 2, 3, 5, 2, 4, 7, 54];
let len = arr.length;
let num = 6;
console.log(consecutive(arr, len, num));
```

Get Wrong Output

```
[2,4]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could store the target index of wrong items and if no one to filter out check the next elements if they sum up to the wanted value.

```js
function consecutive(array, num) {
    return array.filter(
        (wrong => (v, i, a) => {
            if (i <= wrong) return false;
            let sum = 0, j = i;
            while (j < a.length) {
                if ((sum += a[j]) === num) {
                    wrong = j;
                    return false;
                }
                j++;
            }
            return true;
        })
        (-1)
    );
}

console.log(consecutive([1, 2, 3, 5, 2, 4, 7, 54], 6));
```